# How do I turn the result of GetField() into a usable object?

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

In the code below, the class `ButtonScript` has a field called `buttonObj` which is of type `GameObject`

```
var button = gameObject.AddComponent<ButtonScript>();
var obj = button.GetType().GetField("buttonObj");
Debug.Log(obj); //prints UnityEngine.GameObject
Debug.Log(obj.name);  //compilation error
```

The error on that last line is:

```
Type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' does not contain a definition for 'name'...
```

Why does it say it's a `GameObject` when it's logged, but says it's a `FieldInfo` object when I try to use it?

How can I get it so that I can treat it like a`GameObject`?

Comment: the `ToString` of `FieldInfo` likely returns that string.

Comment: Is this a simple typo? The property name is `Name`, not `name`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad no, lowercase `name` is right http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the `obj` variable is `FieldInfo` and not `GameObject`.

The `FieldInfo` class represents metadata information about the `buttonObj` field. It does not contain its value.

To get its value, you have to use the `GetValue` method like this:

```
var button = gameObject.AddComponent<ButtonScript>();

var field = button.GetType().GetField("buttonObj");

//Assuming that the type of the field is GameObject
var obj = (GameObject)field.GetValue(button); 

var name = obj.name;
```